How can I correct/eliminate this bone jittering in animations?
While still searching for a way to pose my FK bones individually, I am trying to get around a solution by moving the entire rig to the position I want the parent bone to be, and then adjusting each bone in the chain back to the position I want it in. This should be sufficient, but when I animate it, it looks like each bone is trying to follow its' parent bone in-between key frames.
Here is a short video I made of the issue:
Bone jittering between keys
I'm sure the issue is caused by the bone following the path of its' parent between key frames, but I'm not sure how to prevent that from happening.
Thanks in advance!

This is why IK was invented. Why don't you use it?

The bone chain I'm actually using it on is 17 bones long, and I have not found a way to set up IK in a way that actually works.

Well, it is better to get a step back and describe what you are trying to active. That is the goal of your setup, maybe selecting this approach is not so useful as you think. From my perspective, the problem may be a loop in parents, but I'm not sure without looking at the setup

Sorry for the delay, just now getting back to checking this. What I was trying to do was make a snake sway back and forth, bone by bone. IK was not providing the smooth movements, even when I was somewhat able to get it to behave. I found a solution, going to add it to my original post. Is there a way to add a video without using an external site like youtube?

No, I even have some problems with gif's

I agree with Crantisz, this is a prime example for using IK.

The bone chain can be however long you need it to be. Just limit the chain length to whatever you require, if you don't want it to go until the root.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/tracking/ik_solver.html

